# Program a button be pressed a maximum of once every 5 seconds in java

Tags: java, swing, printing, delay, jbutton

For a current project we need to allow a user only to press a button once every 5 or so seconds. We use a button to start a print job but we need to stop users from spamming the button and starting a dozen print jobs.

We are currently trying with the following code but it seems to que the clicks even when the button is disabled. So after a 5 second delay the clicks are registered even tough in that time the button is disabled.

```
    private void Button1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

        Button1.setEnabled(false);
        pressCount++;
        System.out.println("Press count: " + pressCount);
    PrintJob print = new PrintJob();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GUIFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        print.PrintJob();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GUIFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you call `Button1.setEnabled(false)` on the GUI Thread (EDT)?

Comment: I tink setEnabled is one of a few swing related methods that you can call of the EDT

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Program a button be pressed a maximum of once every 5 seconds in java

- have look at [JButton#setMultiClickThreshhold(long threshhold)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMultiClickThreshhold%28long%29)
- proper way is add [`Swing Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) to the [`JButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) instead of [`ActionListener][4]` and by using [`Swing Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to block [`isEnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html#isEnabled%28%29)

Comment: Thanks a lot! i set used the following code to fix my problem:Button1.setMultiClickThreshhold(5000);

Comment: glad to help you, and you change the JButtons Icon, until is blocked

Answer (score 3):

Don't make the EDT wait for 5 seconds. You should use another thread to sleep for 5 seconds and the setting the button enabled. Something like this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      // handle it
    }
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        Button1.setEnabled(true);
      }
    });
  }
}).start();
```